# How do I stop the account chooser window opening UNDER the current window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth

Intermittently I get periods where calling gapi.auth.authorize results in an account picker window being opened **under** my application window, where of course it goes un-noticed by the user.

Is there any way to force it on top, or at least detect it's been opened so I can alert the user?

I'm currently testing on Chrome, but I've seen it on Firefox too.

To recreate...

1. Be logged in to more than one Google account
2. Go to my app, which makes a call to gapi.auth.authorize
3. Normally, there will be a popup window asking me to choose which Google account I want to authenticate with. However sometimes, this popup window is underneath my app window, so is obscured by it and not noticed by the user

**What it should (and sometimes does) look like...**

[image]

**What it shouldn't, but sometimes does look like ...**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or something that shows what's happening?

Comment: what do you mean by " go to my app" ?

Comment: @pinoyyid are you building some chrome extension ? because i cannot reproduce this error , a screenshot will be better.

Comment: this is a sample page : https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html , is it possible re produce the error using this one ? cause it always opens the prompt in new window .

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 34.0.1847.131m and IE10

Comment: It sometimes works for me too. The problem is intermittent. It's not an extension, it's a simple web page app. By "go to my app", I mean enter the URL of my app in a browser

Comment: I am afraid there is no solution to your problem. If you do find one, it would probably involve a hack that the Chrome (or the Google Sign In) team would tackle and fix (because it means pop under and other annoyances are possible). :( Just inform the user that they should look for a popup window if you gt the focus too fast without a response (the user approved the request, or explicitly denied).

Comment: Can you provide a demo that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to reproduce your issue with the popup launching in the background, but I may have a solution for you.

This is a hack, but it avoids having to modify Google's code directly.

This is the important part, a demo is provided below. Essentially you are overriding `window.open` and focusing the popup shortly after it's created. After the window is opened, you restore `window.open`'s default functionality.

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {

  // Hijack window.open
  var windowOpen = window.open;
  window.open = function(url, name, options) {
    var newWindow = windowOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    setTimeout(function() {
      newWindow.focus();
    }, 0);
    return newWindow;
  };

  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);

  // Release window.open
  window.open = windowOpen;
  return false;
}
```

**Demo**:
http://jsbin.com/sefozinu/1/edit

*Later versions of Chrome and FireFox have been known to not respect `window.focus`.*

Comment: Novel approach. I'll give it a go. Could you update your question with what, if any, cross browser issues you might expect. I've awarded the bounty, but won't mark the answer accepted until I've tested it.

Comment: @pinoyyid -- Like I said, I haven't been able to reproduce the bug after multiple tries, I know it exists as I've seen it happen a few months ago. As far as I know, this is the only potential fix, unless you're developing a browser plugin or some other app with elevated permissions.

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work (Chrome 30.0). The auth window is still below my app window. I can see that newWindow has been set to "DOMException".

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps, and -like others- was unable to reproduce this. (using Chrome 34.0.1847.131 on Windows 8.1)

The problem may be the browser, not the contents..

It looks are using a Chrome/Chromium browser i do not know of. Eyeing the screenshot, i see a soccer ball in the window top-left corner. Can you please specify it, for us to reproduce?

(Or consider installing a new vanilla, mainstream Chrome browser as a test baseline.)

Comment: Re-read the question and you'll see that (a) the problem seems intermittent, and (b) occurs with both Chrome and Firefox. It's hard to track down the cause because Google silently updates the gapi library, so one never knows if the Javascript in that library is a contributing factor. The fact the question has 6 upvotes suggests I'm not alone in seeing this problem. btw It's a football, not a soccer ball. That just happens to be the logo I associated with my Chrome user.

Comment: Please state the Firefox or Chrome version, all we got now are the football screenshots.